# C++ Variadic function with inherited objects references and base class

Tags: c++, templates, asynchronous, variadic-templates, c++20

I am writing a class to implement and signal-slot mechanism.
The signal can emit a series of events that are all derived from a base struct called "base_event". Below is how I defined the base_event and an example of a derived struct:

```
struct base_event
{
        std::string _id = "base_event";
};

struct select_next_event : public base_event
{
        select_next_event(uint32_t tr_num) : base_event(), _tr_num(tr_num)
        {
                base_event::_id = "select_next_event";
        };

        uint32_t _tr_num;
};
```

Then my emit function signature is:

```
template<typename... Args>
void emit(Args... args)
{
   ..... All the logic .....
}
```

Then when I want to emit an event, I write something like:

```
slot.emit(select_next_event{3});
```

Up to there, everything is working fine.

My issue is that I would like to add an asynchronous (non-blocking) emit function to my library. To that goal, I write a second function (I am using c++20 so I can do perfect forwarding):

```
void emit_async(Args... args)
{
     auto send_async = std::async(std::launch::async, 
                [this, ... args = std::forward<Args>(args)](){ emit(std::forward<Args>(args)...); });
}
```

The problem arises if I write:

```
slot.emit_async(select_next_event{3});
```

Then when I read the event in my slot function, the value of **_tr_num** is not forwarded (always equal to 0)

However, if I write :

```
auto send_async = std::async(std::launch::async, 
                [this](){slot.emit(select_next_event{3});});
```

Then the value of **_tr_num** is correctly forwarded to the slot function.

I do not see where is my error?

Pi-r

**[EDIT]**

As requested, and sorry for my lack of clarity, please find bellow a minimal example that demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

struct base_event
{
        std::string _id = "base_event";
};

struct select_next_event : public base_event
{
        select_next_event(uint32_t tr_num) : base_event(), _tr_num(tr_num)
        {
                base_event::_id = "select_next_event";
        };

        uint32_t _tr_num;
};

template<typename... Args>
void emit(Args... args)
{
        int i = 0;

        ([&] (auto & arg)
        {
                ++i;
                std::cout << "input " << i << " = " << arg._id.c_str() << " " << arg._tr_num << std::endl;
        } (args), ...);
}


template<typename... Args>
void emit_async(Args... args)
{
     auto send_async = std::async(std::launch::async,
                [... args = std::forward<Args>(args)](){ emit(std::forward<Args>(args)...); });
}

int main()
{
    emit(select_next_event{3});

    //emit_async(select_next_event{3}); // if added, it produces a compilation eror
}
```

I do compile the code with:

`g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`

I think this example presents the problem I have as if I remove the comment for the async, I do have a compilation error:

```
main.cpp:38:82: error: binding reference of type ‘std::remove_reference<select_next_event>::type&’ {aka ‘select_next_event&’} to ‘const select_next_event’ discards qualifiers
```

I do hope that now I have created a clearer explanation of my issue! If anything is missing/misleading, please let me know!

Comment: A little nitpicking about your choice of tags: You use *template parameter packs*. Variadic functions are something different (think the old C functions `printf` and `scanf`).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mre]. Your example code is not complete nor easily tested. Instead of mixing it with verbal explanations, post the code as one complete chunk that can be copy-pasted into a compiler and reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, `emit_async(Args... args)` is pass by value, so `Args...` is always a value type, you need to add *forwarding reference* to it.

Second and more important, you construct `args` with *init-capture* `[... args = std::forward<Args>(args)]`, but since lambda's `operator()` is implicitly `const`, you cannot forward `args` in the function body since `args` are also `const`-qualified, instead you need to add `mutable` keyword for lambda

```
template<typename... Args>
void emit_async(Args&&... args) {
  auto send_async = std::async(
    std::launch::async,
    [...args = std::forward<Args>(args)] mutable 
      { emit(std::forward<Args>(args)...); });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/czoWaf8vW)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is true that now it compiles but the variable  "_tr_num" is not passed. It is equal to 0.

Comment: @PMDP3 Didn't the Demo print out `3`? Could you provide an example that reproduces the problem?